# Resize image android

Tags: android, kotlin

I want to write a simple code - resize function without library. I must use getPixel and setPixel, result may be without normal quality. But I don't know how make it.

```
fun resuzeimage(bitmap:Bitmap,newWidth,newHeight){

 for (j in 0 until bitmap.height) {
        for (i in 0 until butmap.width) {
           ///code
        }
    }

}
```

Pleas, help me

Answer (score 1):

```
  fun resizeImage(yourBitmap: Bitmap, newWidth :Int, newHeight :Int):Bitmap
{

    var resized = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(yourBitmap!!, newWidth, newHeight, true)
    return resized
}
```

You can change height and width return type as per your need.